# Changing JVM in Java

Tags: java, openjdk, jdk, jre

I only recently discovered the different JVM's on the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines) page and thought I'd start tinkering. Its been difficult to find documentation on how to configure Java on Ubuntu though.

Lets say I wanted to change the JRE or JDK that I'm using, I could crack open a terminal and say

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And then pick from one of the installed versions.

If I'm understanding JVM's right (which I may very well be not), You can configure the openJDK to use alternative JVM's (Eg JAMVM) and run it as such

```
jamvm -jar foo.jar
```

2 questions,

1: Do i have the concept of a JVM right? As in, is this possible?

2: If so how do i configure the JVM and switch the default to a JVM of my choosing?

Comment: Great, add a good answer to your question (you can answer them yourself) and get some up votes!

Comment: @BrunoPereira Done! Hopefully that covers the bunch.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feel free to use this as a reference to tinkering with Java at runtime.

### Choosing your JRE

To choose your JRE, use

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

This will give something like the following output.

```
  Selection    Path                                            Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java         1061      auto mode
* 1            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre/bin/java         1061      manual mode
  2            /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/jre/bin/java             63        manual mode
  3            /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java   1051      manual mode
```

You can then select which Java runtime you want through the number selection.

---

### Choosing your JVM

Sun/Oracle have two JVM choices, -server and -client.
If you select the OpenJDK as your Java runtime environment you have additional options.

When you type `java` into the terminal with no other parameters, the help lists several optional VMs. I'm not sure which ones come with OpenJDK but 3 popular ones are JamVM, Zero and Cacao

To use these, simply type

```
java -jamvm 'your other parameters here'
java -cacao 'your other parameters here'
java -zero 'your other parameters here'
java -server 'your other parameters here
```

The -server VM is normally the default. You can also specify `-client` but in 64-bit IcedTea6 it appears to run the same version as -server.
There are most likely others but I find the default option to be the most responsive.

---

### Setting your Memory

Finally, how to set the memory of Java (just because)

```
java -Xmx1024m -Xms128m 'your other parameters here'
```

This  limits the memory allowed for the Java program to a maximum of 1024 MB, and sets its initial memory size to 128 MB. This is a great way of defining minimum system requirements. The [Java 6 man page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) for the `java` command describes these options and others.

That's all. If anyone has additional Java tweaks for Ubuntu then leave them in the comments and I'll add them.

Comment: There are about 47 executable files in $JAVA_HOME/bin and $JAVA_HOME/jre/bin which cries for an script to update all the entries in the alternatives system. See the /usr/lib/jvm/.java*.jinfo files.

Comment: How do I set the default JVM? From what I've heard, -server has long start-up times, so why isn't -client the default anyway for a user installation?

Comment: Is there a way to actually change the defaults, or do you have to explicitly set the JVM and memory limits each time (or in each individual startup script)?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default JVM inside an OpenJDK installation you need to edit the jvm.cfg configuration file located inside the /usr/lib/jvm/java-**version**-openjdk-**arch**/jre/lib/**arch**/jvm.cfg

Ubuntu expose the jvm.cfg file inside the /etc/ directory depending on OpenJDK version.
/etc/java-6-openjdk/jvm-**arch**.cfg
or
/etc/java-7-openjdk/jvm-**arch**.cfg

The top most
-**jvmname** KNOWN
line inside the jvm.cfg file determine the default JVM.

There is no configuration tool available thus you have to locate and edit these files manually.