# How Can I Change Jamvm on my embedded system to Openjdk?

Tags: java, openjdk

I have one Embedded System Currently working On jamvm.
I Want to change it to openjdk.
How Can I do that???

Comment: Is this what you are asking for? http://askubuntu.com/questions/107278/changing-jvm-in-java